# Derivative of determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices, derivatives

I would like to know how to calculate:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\det \big(A_1(t), A_2(t), \ldots, A_n (t) \big).$$

Comment: What is your mean $A_i(t)$? $i$-th column of $A$?

Comment: Readers of this thread may be interested in the "[Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)" by Petersen & Pedersen, which has explicit formulas for tons of things like the derivatives of the determinant, eigenvalues, and inverse of a matrix.  A few proofs, but mostly just references.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The formula is $$d(\det(m))=\det(m)Tr(m^{-1}dm)$$ where $dm$ is the matrix with $dm_{ij}$ in the entires. The derivation is based on Cramer's rule, that $m^{-1}=\frac{Adj(m)}{\det(m)}$. It is useful in old-fashioned differential geometry involving principal bundles.

I noticed Terence Tao posted a nice blog entry on [it](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/). So I probably do not need to explain more at here.

Comment: we can write it as a sum?, and how?
please

Comment: Try to write down the 2 by 2 case yourself and see how it works.

Comment: for n=2, i must have $ \frac{d}{dt}\det \big(A_1(t),A_2(t)\big)=$
$\det \big(A'_1(t),A_2(t)\big)+ \det \big(A_1(t),A'_2(t))\big) $ but how ?

Comment: how to use the formula? please

Comment: Find a DG book on principal bundles.

Comment: what is the relation ?

Comment: I have updated.

Answer (score 21):

Think I can provide a proof for Matias' formula.

So, let

$$
A(t) = \mathrm{det}\left( A_1(t), \dots , A_n(t) \right) \ .
$$

By definition,

$$
\frac{dA(t)}{dt} = \mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{A(t+h) - A(t)}{h} = \mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\det (A_1(t+h), \dots, A_n(t+h)) - \det(A_1(t), \dots , A_n(t))}{h} 
$$

Now, we subtract and add

$$
\det(A_1(t), A_2(t+h), \dots , A_n(t+h))
$$

obtaining:

$$
\frac{dA(t)}{dt} = \mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\det (A_1(t+h), A_2(t+h),\dots, A_n(t+h)) - \det(A_1(t), A_2(t+h), \dots , A_n(t+h))}{h} + 
\mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{
\det(A_1(t), A_2(t+h), \dots , A_n(t+h))-\det(A_1(t), \dots , A_n(t))}{h}
$$

Now we focus on the first addend, which is

$$
\det \left( \mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{A_1(t+h) - A_1(t)}{h}, \mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} A_2(t+h), \dots,\mathrm{lim}_{h\rightarrow 0} A_n(t+h) \right) 
$$

That is,

$$
\det (A_1'(t), A_2(t), \dots , A_n(t)) \ .
$$

Now, let's go for the second addend to which we substract and add

$$
\det(A_1(t), A_2(t), A_3(t+h), \dots , A_n(t+h)) \ .
$$

From which we will obtain the term

$$
\det (A_1(t), A'_2(t), A_3(t), \dots , A_n(t)) \ .
$$

Keep on doing analogous operations till you get

$$
\det (A_1(t), A_2(t), \dots , A_{n-1}(t), A_n'(t)) \ .
$$

Answer (score 17):

Like product rule:

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\det(A_1(t),A_2(t),...,A_n(t))=\det(A_1^{'}(t),A_2(t),A_n(t))+\det(A_1(t),A_2^{'}(t),...,A_n(t))+...+\det(A_1(t),A_2(t),...,A_n^{'}(t))                                  $$

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what OP wants.

Comment: @kiroro helped you?

Comment: yes this is the formula that I want, but I'm not yet arrived

Comment: @kiroro I'll be happy to explain later!! In my country it's too late, ok? I'm going to sleep. You need it fast? But it seems that you are having good results. nice!!!

Comment: ok thank you good night

Answer (score 6):

In the previous answers it was not explicitly said that there is also the Jacobi's formula to compute the derivative of the determinant of a matrix.

You can find it here well explained: [JACOBI'S FORMULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula).

And it basically states that:

[image]

Where the adj(A) is the adjoint matrix of A. How to compute the adjugate matrix is explained here: [ADJUGATE MATRIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Is there an explicit derivation of second-order derivative of determinant when A is singular?

Comment: Note that when $A$ is invertible, $\mathrm{adj}(A) = A^{-1}\det A$, so the formula is just $(d/dt)\det A(t) = (\det A)\mathrm{Tr}[ A^{-1} (dA/dt)]$.