# Is there a known notation for $\nabla_{\nabla_ii}f$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $(M,g)$  a clsoed Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ its Levi-Civita connection and $f$ a smooth function. Is there a known notation for $\mathsf{tr}\ \nabla_{\nabla_{\bullet} \bullet}f=\sum_i \nabla_{\nabla_ii}f$?

By simplifying it using definition of Christoffel symbols:
$$\sum_i \nabla_{\nabla_ii}f=\sum_i \nabla_{\Gamma_{ii}^k\partial_k}f=\sum_i \Gamma_{ii}^k\nabla_{\partial_k}f=\sum_i \Gamma_{ii}^k {\partial_k}f$$

and the question reduce to understand that what is the $\sum_i \Gamma_{ii}^k$ but this remind me nothing. I have googled "*trace of Christoffel symbols*" but the search result was [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1905648/272127) that deals with $\sum_k \Gamma_{ik}^k$ instead of $\sum_i \Gamma_{ii}^k$.

**Motivation:** This equation comes from computing the trace of hessian of $f:=\frac{1}{2}\|X\|^2$ for some vector field $X$.

$\small{\text{mini-question:}}$ As I know, here we cannot use normal  coordinates technique because the wanted quantity is not tensorial. Am I right?

Comment: How did you get to the point where you want to use the symbol $\nabla_i i$ to denote $\sum_{k}\Gamma^{k}_{ii}\partial_k$?
Also, where did you find the expression $\sum_{ik}\Gamma^k_{ii}\partial_k f$?
If you just came up with it, I doubt there is a stablished notation for it.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: it is not $\nabla_ii$ instead $\nabla_{\nabla_ii}$ but their action on functions are equal but not action on tensors. Also It appeared in the trace of hessian of $f$.

Comment: The trace of the Hessian is
$$\mathrm{tr}(Hf) = \sum_{\alpha,\beta}g^{\alpha\beta}\left(\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta f - \sum_\gamma\Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}\partial_\gamma f\right)$$
I guess you mean the term $\sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}g^{\alpha\beta}\Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}\partial_\gamma f$.
Thanks for answering. Still, I don't see why you would write it like that. Do you have any reference of usage of that notation? This is to satisfy my own curiosity, and I guess for the clarity of the question.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: more specifically I am computing the hessian of $f:=\frac{1}{2}\|X\|^2$ then tracing the result.

Comment: So... why do you want to find an alternative notation for $\sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}g^{\alpha\beta}\Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}\partial_\gamma f$? Personally, I think it is pretty clear as it is written.

I don't see how the form of the $f$ you are working with has any impact on the notation.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz: You meant there is no other known symbol for this quantity like Laplacian or something similar?

Comment: There is none that I personally know of. I'm not saying no such notation exists, I'm just saying that I don't see the need for such a notation.