# Conditions for nonsingularity of a matrix with trigonometric elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, determinant, matrix-rank

Let $q$ be a positive integer and define $Q\triangleq \{1,2,...,q\}$. For all $i\in Q$, and all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, define
\begin{align}
f_{i,k}\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}\cos k\theta_i&\sin k\theta_i\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times 2},
\end{align}
where $\theta_i>0$. 
Define
\begin{align}
P_{q,k}\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}f_{1,k}&f_{2,k}&...&f_{q,k}\\
f_{1,k+1}&f_{2,k+1}&...&f_{q,k+1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&~&\vdots\\
f_{1,k+2q-1}&f_{2,k+2q-1}&...&f_{q,k+2q-1}\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2q\times 2q}
\end{align}

In the case, where $q=1$, it follows that
\begin{align}
\det~ P_{1,k}&=\det\begin{bmatrix}\cos k\theta_1&\sin k\theta_1\\\cos (k+1)\theta_1&\sin (k+1)\theta_1\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\cos k\theta_1\sin (k+1)\theta_1-\sin k\theta_1\cos (k+1)\theta_1\\&=\sin \theta_1.
\end{align}
Thus, if $\sin\theta_1\neq 0$, then $P_{1,k}$ is nonsingular for all  $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

For $q\in\{2,3,4,...\}$, what are the conditions on $\theta_i$, where $i\in Q$, such that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$,  $P_{q,k}$ is nonsingular?

Comment: Have you tried computing the next example? Your question is essentially «what is the determinant of this matrix?»

Comment: After computing the first few determinants, we see that $\det P_{q,k}$ is a power of two times $\prod_{i<j}(\cos\theta_i-\cos\theta_j)^2\prod_i\sin\theta_i$. It is easy to see, by [differentiating the determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/276804/274) with respect to $k$, that the determinant is independent of $k$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I haven't. I thought computing the determinant is not necessary to check the nonsingularity of a matrix. Maybe by some operations on rows or columns we can show that the matrix is full rank.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  How do you see that? Can you please write that as an answer?

Comment: As  said: simply compute the derivative of the determinant! Use the formula for that derivative to which I linked. I will not write down the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Computing the derivative of the determinant of your matrix with respect to $k$ we see at once that it is independent of $k$, so we just take $k=1$.

Next we know that $$\cos(n\theta)=T_n(\cos\theta),$$ with $T_n$ the $n$th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind. Smilarly, $$\sin(n\theta)=U_n(\cos(\theta))/\sin(\theta),$$ with $U_n$ the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind now.

$U_n$ and $T_n$ are polynomials of degree $n$. Using these facts and row operations you can considerably simplify your matrix until it becomes something similar to a Vandermonde matrix, up to some factors, and using that you should find the formula I wrote in a comment above for the determinant.

Comment: MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I have been trying to follow your comments and answer, but I cannot do the row operations after using Chebyshev polynomials. I was wondering if any critical step is missed in your explanations.

Comment: You have to tell me at what point you get stuck.