# Show the relation: $\partial_c g = g g^{ab} (\partial_c g_{ab})$

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

In order to follow my book on General Relativity, I need to prove the above relation, where $g_{ab}$ is some general metric, $\partial_c$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to $x^c$, $\partial_c=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^c}$ and, as it's said on the title, $g$ is the determinant of the metric matrix.

On the book it's said (and seems like it's useful for the proof) that the cofactor of the element $g_{ab}$ in this determinant is $gg_{ab}$, but I can't see why this would be true...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not really sure it does... The title looked promising but I haven't been able to figure it out from there

Comment: Note that $Tr(m^{-1}dm)$ in one of the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/276799/629362) translates to $g^{ab} \partial_c g_{ab}$.

Comment: Solved! Thanks!!